# hovering over gridview row overrides alternating row style

Tags: asp.net, gridview

below is the code that works fine but the only problem i have is : overriding the alternative row with `backgroundColor='white'` how can i have my alternative color when `onmouseout` ?

```
 <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="#DEEEE9" Font-Size="8pt" />

if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
{
    e.Row.Attributes.Add("onmouseover", "this.style.backgroundColor='#C2D69B'");
    e.Row.Attributes.Add("onmouseout", "this.style.backgroundColor='white'");
    e.Row.Attributes.Add("style", "cursor:pointer;");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I'm not a fan of setting these in the code-behind, I think something these lines would take care of you:

```
e.Row.Attributes.Add("onmouseover", "this.setAttribute('bgColor', this.style.backgroundColor); this.style.backgroundColor = '#C2D69B';");
e.Row.Attributes.Add("onmouseout", "this.style.backgroundColor = this.getAttribute('bgColor');");
```

Comment: Sorry, not enough coffee yet.  I had some quotes mixed up.  I think the above code should work. Here's a working example http://jsfiddle.net/chprpipr/JqDda/3/

Comment: there is no effect whatsoever it does not do anything.

Comment: I've removed the anonymous function calls, which seemed to be tripping it up.  Does the blue row in my working example work for you?

Comment: i have updated your new code and its acting little bit funky, i have row of white bgcolor and alternative color which is `"#DEEEE9` and when i hover over white bgcolor row then my bgcolor becomes `#C2D69B` and if i hover over alternative rows then it works fine.

Comment: the above answer did not fix my problem but closing this question for the sake of it